# Array inside an instance/object: why doesn't this work on java?

Tags: java

Im doing some java exercises and i need to create an object with an array inside. This array uses variables from the object itself like so:

```
public class Persons {
    String name;
    String nationality;
    String dateOfBirth;
    String[] passport={name, nationality, dateOfBirth};
    int seatNumber;
}
```

But in the main when trying to print Persons.passport all three fields are null no matter what. Instead the object needs to be like so:

```
public class Persons {
    String name;
    String nationality;
    String dateOfBirth;
    String[] passport;
    int seatNumber;
}
```

and in main we need to attribute passport like this: `person.passport= new String[]{person.name, person.nationality, person.dateOfBirth};`

Why is that? why doesnt the first one works?

Comment: In the first one, you are setting your array with nulls, since you haven't assigned anything to the strings. Even if you had, when you reassign the string variables in the constructor, the array would still have the original values because java String's are immutable.

Comment: @NomadMaker: Not really because strings are immutable. You'd see the same thing with StringBuilder, if you change the value of the field, rather than modifying the object that the field value referred to.

Comment: @JonSkeet I was trying to simplify things a bit (perhaps too much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a class, we cannot fill an array with values. The values do not exist at [compile-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time).

One way to accomplish your goal is to define a [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) that at [run-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_(computing)) generates an array containing the values present at that moment.

```java
public class Person {
    // Member fields.

    String name;
    String nationality;
    String dateOfBirth;
    int seatNumber;

    // Methods.

    public String[] passport () 
    {
        String[] x = new String[ 3 ] ;
        x[ 0 ] = this.name ;
        x[ 1 ] = this.nationality ;
        x[ 2 ] = this.dateOfBirth ;
        return x ;
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
Person alice = new Person( "Alice" , "CA" , "1960-01-23" ) ;
String[] passportData = alice.passport() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields that are in passport do not change, then I suggest setting passport in your constructor

```
public class Persons {
  String name;
  String nationality;
  String dateOfBirth;
  String[] passport;
  int seatNumber;

  public Persons(String name, String nationality, String dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    passport = new String[] {name, nationality, dateOfBirth};
  }
}
```

If however, you plan on mutating the values of those fields, then you should get rid of the passport field entirely and have a getter method which builds the array when you ask for it.

This technique is also somewhat safer as it prevents other classes from mutating that array owned by the Persons object.

```
public class Persons {
  String name;
  String nationality;
  String dateOfBirth;
  int seatNumber;

  public Persons(String name, String nationality, String dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }

  public String[] getPassport() {
    return new String[] {name, nationality, dateOfBirth};
  }
}
```